# Never clear .bash_history (HISTFILE)

Tags: bash, command-history

Is there any command that I could use that makes `.bash_history` never clear itself?
After a certain amount of commands it just clear itself.

I think this works but I'm not sure?

```
HISTFILESIZE=100000000000
```

I did run this but I'm not sure if it does what I asked.

And I know that if the file gets too big then bash might be slower, but I'll just move it out every now and then.

Comment: If this is the case then i will answer the question myself.

Comment: Please capitalize your Is. It is annoying that we have to [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/166220/revisions) [that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/166146/revisions) [for you](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/165687/revisions) [so many](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/165474/revisions) [times](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/164820/revisions) [on so](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/164596/revisions) [many](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/164197/revisions) [different](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/163653/revisions) questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line to your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`):

```
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTFILESIZE=
```

From [Bash History Facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html) documentation:

> If HISTFILESIZE is not set, no truncation is performed.

Comment: +1, I didn't know we could leave it unset! I suggest [you add the lines](http://superuser.com/a/183980/151431) to `~/.profile` not `~/.bashrc` though.

Comment: @terdon: I think `.profile` is for thing that is not specifically related to `bash`, `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` are very related, so `.bashrc` is more suitable.

Comment: Well, yes and no. You can always use `~/.bash_profile` to make it bash-specific. The point is that `.bashrc` is read each time a new non-login shell is started so having env variables set there makes them be re-read for every shell which is not elegant. Still, you're right about this causing issues with other shells. In any case, you will need to _also_ add them to `.profile` (or another file that is read by login shells) else the history file will get truncated each time a login shell is started. See [BASH history truncated to 500 lines on each login](http://superuser.com/q/575479)

Comment: @terdon: Good point, updated my answer.

Comment: But if i type `100000` it will still get cleared after `100000`  (bytes, commands whatever) right?