# How to see all commands since last system install(5 months)?

Tags: bash, command-history, bashrc, bash-expansion

using Linux has been an interesting quest for the best system to fulfill my needs and wishes. 5 months ago I arrived to a good comfort-zone.
Now I want to change my harddrive. In order to make my initial customization more efficiently, I thought of looking up **all the commands I've typed in the bash since my last installation**. The `history` command and my `.bash_history` file under `~$` and `~#` only show the command of my last days..

> How do I do this?

and/or

> How to "best" keep track of all (successfull) command I type?

Comment: The premise is faulty.  **Not every change you've made can be understood or replicated from the commands alone.**  How about `sudo vim /etc/*.conf`?  If you want [declarative configuration management](https://cfengine.com/learn/why-cfengine/), to state the end goal and have your system arrive there, you'll need much better tools than a command history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will unfortunately not be able to see them all. You should have configured this just after system installation.

There are two environment variables of interest here, `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE`.  The former controls the number of commands stored for the current session. The latter defines how many commands are kept in the history file.  You can see how these are currently set by:

```
echo "$HISTSIZE"  
echo "$HISTFILESIZE"
```

You can define these in your `.bashrc` file (or the system bashrc file) by adding the following lines:

```
HISTSIZE=[5000 seems to be a common default]
HISTFILESIZE=[large number of your choice]
```

Note again that only `HISTFILESIZE` affects the history file, and `HISTSIZE` is just what is stored in the history list for a given session.

Also, check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166995/150445).

Comment: thanx! where is the system bashrc file? is it `/root/.bashrc` or `/etc/skel/.bashrc` or ...? what happens if I leave `HISTSIZE= ` empty? what happens if I leave `HISTFILESIZE= ` empty?

Comment: The location will depend on your distribution, but will almost certainly just be right in `/etc/`.  In Arch Linux, it is `/etc/bash.bashrc`.  Like I say, the file name can vary but it should look something similar to this and the name should be pretty obvious.  As far as what happens if it's not defined on your system, and it probably is, I have no idea.  I'll let you try that out on your system ;)

Comment: well, I have a file `/etc/bash.bashrc` but this has no `HISTSIZE` nor `HISTFILESIZE` on my Debian... and well, I see two options for letting it empty. Either there will be no history at all (zero) or there will be no limit at all (infinite?) ... I'll only be able to post if empty means zero (for the other option I am unfortunately incapable of writing an infinite number of commands!)

Comment: Try `sudo grep -r  HISTFILE /etc/*` just to see if it's defined elsewhere, like `/etc/profile` or something.  If it's not defined anywhere, including your user's `.bashrc` files, there could be another default value.  According to man history: "Initially, 20 events are retained in the history list.", though I'm unclear if this pertains to the history file.

Comment: oh! I have a `/etc/skel/.bashrc` file with a `HISTFILESIZE` entry which I now edited... one last thing: what about my 1st question? is it possible to read **all** the commands I typed since, say, september? or are they all lost :( ?

Comment: If they aren't in the bash history file you're sunk.  But let me make an important point here.  The files in `/etc/skel/' are used to create files in the home directories of _new_ users only.  That is the only time that file will be read by the system.  It should be the file that was used to create any users on your system, thus your `~/.bashrc` should have whatever `HISTFILESIZE` entry you found in `/etc/skel/.bashrc'.  Your `.bashrc` file is where you want to make that change.  You will need to log out and back in or at least start a new bash instance (new terminal) for that to take effect.